# diff_drive changes the wheel's parent link

Tags: gazebo, tf2, tf2-ros, diff-drive-controller, ros-galactic

So this is kind of a wierd issue.

I have a two-wheeled robot with a caster and i'm using diff_drive to test it in gazebo with ros2-galactic.
my tf tree is a little different where my base_link is not the root link.

in my urdf I set the wheels parant link to be base_link, and so it appears just as the robot spawns.

```
<joint name="br_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="br_wheel"/>
  <origin xyz="0.0 ${-wheels_base/2} ${wheel_radius}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
</joint>


<gazebo>
<plugin name='diff_drive' filename='libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so'>
  <ros>
    <namespace>/my_robot</namespace>
  </ros>

  <update_rate>500</update_rate>
  <num_wheel_pairs>1</num_wheel_pairs>

  <left_joint>bl_wheel_joint</left_joint>
  <right_joint>br_wheel_joint</right_joint>

  <!-- kinematics -->
  <wheel_separation>${wheels_base} </wheel_separation>

  <wheel_diameter>${2*wheel_radius}</wheel_diameter>

  <!-- limits -->
  <max_wheel_torque>20</max_wheel_torque>
  <max_wheel_acceleration>2.0</max_wheel_acceleration>

  <!-- output -->
  <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
  <publish_odom_tf>false</publish_odom_tf>
  <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>

  <robot_base_frame>base_footprint</robot_base_frame>
  <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
  
</plugin>
```

but as soon as diff_drive starts publishing the transform, for some reason the parant link changes to my root link.

[image: tf2 tree]

I assume its bacause diff_drive takes the root link as parent link when publishing the transform, although I dont understand why.
I tried playing wroung with the <robot_base_frame> tag but it appears that it was depracted after transitioning to ros2. Any thoughts on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You should change robot_base_frame to your actual "base_link" - since your robot has no "base_footprint":

```
<robot_base_frame>base_link</robot_base_frame>
```

Note though: this may cause a different issue - as I presume the diff_drive plugin will be publishing the odom->base_link TF transform, and then base_link will have two parents - this often causes problems with TF lookup.